# ConfigParser has no attribute

Tags: python, flask, configparser

config.cfg

```
[database]
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db'
```

config.py

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from os import makedirs
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("server", "config", "config.cfg")):
    config.read(os.path.join("server", "config", "config.cfg"))
```

base.py

```
from server import app
from server.config import config
print (config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
```

AttributeError: module 'server.config.config' has no attribute 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access settings in the config file, you will need to use the `.get` method:

```
config.get('database', 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```